# Losing my internet connection

Tags: windows-7, internet

I am using Windows 7 and am connected to my office network.  My internet connection goes out at least once per day and the network icon shows at the bottom of the screen with a yellow caution sign.  I trouble shoot the internet connections and it determines there is an issue with the Local Area Adaptor and resets it. A screen then comes up showing the troubleshooting has completed.  It states the PROBLEMS FOUND is "The default gateway is not available" and shows it as "Fixed" with a green check mark next to it.

The bigger issue occurs less often and there is a red "x" on the network icon.  When this occurs the trouble shooter says I need to plug in the ethernet cable, but it is plugged in.  I have unplugged it from the PC and from the switch for all the internet connections in my section of the office.  The only solution then is to reboot the computer.  No other computer in the office loses their connection either.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Do you want to know how to troubleshoot problems like this? Also, why didn't you give us any problem details? Has this computer always had this problem? When did it start? Is your connection wired or wireless? When it goes out, is the link light still lit? When you say "losing my internet connection", do you mean that the connection to your router is still okay and only your internet connection is lost? Or by "internet connection" do you really mean your connection to your local network?

Comment: I had the same problem on win7 at one point. I worked on troubleshooting it for months.  Eventually it just went away. The only thing that changed along the way that makes it explainable is Windows Updates.  Are you up to date?

Comment: It would be important to know whether you are using Home or Professional. The home version has a lesser quality network stack and will often drop connections where the professional version will not, even on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a full virus scan? It would also be great to try if the problems are not caused by firewall, but being connected whole day without a firewall is a big security issue. You could e.g. install another FW and try it for a few days (and uninstall your current FW, of course (don't forget to export/save your settings)).

And as for the hardware part - have you checked if the network card is well fitted in its socket (if it is a desktop computer)? Have you tried connecting the other end of the cable to another port on the switch?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this thread](http://www.eightforums.com/network-sharing/21748-default-gateway-not-available.html), one of the many possible reasons for the symptoms you describe can be fixed as follows:

> When you get to Device Manager simply highlight the wireless
>   connection you are having problems with, right click it and choose
>   properties then go to the Power Management tab and uncheck the option
>   [Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power].

Another thing to try is to check the vendor of the network card for updated drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Look and see if there are any new drivers for your ethernet card. Even if Windows tells you your driver is up to date, try and check yourself, they are wrong sometimes.

If all of your drivers are up to date, then turn your computer on in safe mode with networking and use it for a bit (you should still be able to work with word and excel type programs).  Safe mode uses the minimum amount of drivers and services.  If it works fine in safe mode we can eliminate a few possibilities.

Also, seems a bit random but, do you have AVG and Windows Defender?  I had a problem a while back with both of them running on Windows 7 where I couldn't connect to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.  I found another posting specific to my Realtec PCI netowrk adaptor.  Their suggestion was to change my settings as follows:
Auto Disable Gigabit > Relink Battery or AC
Green Ethernet > Disable
Energy Efficient Ethernet > Disable

I will let you know how this works out.  So far so good.